# Multi switch tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help me, I need replace (switch) tags in DOM structure. I have this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="title">title 1</div>
                <div class="image">image 1 for title 1</div>
            </div>
       </li>
       <li>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="title">title 2</div>
                <div class="image">image 2 for title 2</div>
            </div>
       </li>
       <li>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="title">title 3</div>
                <div class="image">image 3 for title 3</div>
            </div>
       </li>
       <li>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="title">title 4</div>
                <div class="image">image 4 for title 4</div>
            </div>
       </li>
   </ul>            
</div>
```

And I need this in result, how do I get it?

```
<div class="wrap">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="image">image 1 for title 1</div>
                        <div class="title">title 1</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="image">image 2 for title 2</div>
                        <div class="title">title 2</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="image">image 3 for title 3</div>
                        <div class="title">title 3</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="image">image 4 for title 4</div>
                        <div class="title">title 4</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
```

I was trying use jQuery `.each()` but as a result I getting structure like this

- Image 4
- Image 3
- Image 2
- Image 1
- title 1
- image 4
- image 3
- image 2
- image 1
- title 2
- image 4
- image 3
- image 2
- image 1
- title 3
- image 4
- image 3
- image 2
- image 1
- title 4

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Start by closing the title elements, makes things a lot easier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
$('.block .title').before(function(){
    return $(this).next()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sWneB/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)**

```
$.each($('.wrap .image'), function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

Btw, Your HTML markup is invalid, you should close the div with class `title` properly using `</div>` and I've fixed it for you in the demo.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCQn8/)**